# what is the problem with my http GET?

Tags: string, http, vba, url, get

in VBA i am creating a URL:

```
URL = "http://api.local.yahoo.com/MapsService/V1/geocode?appid=" & yahoo & "&street=" & street & "&city=" & city & "&state=" & state & "&zip=" & zip
```

for example it sets itself to equal this:

```
http://api.local.yahoo.com/MapsService/V1/geocode?appid=username123&street=1893 n. clyde morris blvd &city=daytona beach&state=FL&zip=32117
```

when i manually go to this URL, IT WORKS FINE.

however when i do this:

```
'Create Http object
If IsEmpty(http) Then Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

'Send request To URL
http.Open "GET", URL

http.send
'Get response data As a string

response = http.responseText
```

it's giving me this for the response:

```
response="Watch :   : response : "<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head><title>Yahoo! - 400 Bad Request</title><style>
/* nn4 hide */ 
/*/*/
bod........"
```

please note that 50% of the time it returns the correct URL and 50% it gives me a `400 bad request`

what am i doing wrong?

wrikken has suggested that i get a URLencoder, but i believe that it was encoding it correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to url-encode all your query parameters, otherwise they may result in invalid URLs, depending on their actual value (for instance, a space should be a `+` or a `%20`). Google has a multitude of VBA url encode examples, it appears there's no built-in function for it.

Comment: @wrikken: thank you so much for your help. can you please show me an example

Comment: Quote 'Wrikken': _"Google has a multitude of VBA url encode examples."_

Comment: @wrikken: thank you. im getting THE URL does not use a recognized protocol" - what does this mean?

Comment: @Jenny: then you are probably encoding the _whole url_ (psuedocode:`url-encode(url)`), which is not what you want, you want to only encode the values (pseudo: `"http://api.local.yahoo.com/MapsService/V1/geocode?appid=" & url-encode(yahoo) & "&street=" & url-encode(street) &  .... etc.`

Comment: @wrikken: thank you again. now im getting something crazy like this "http://api.local.yahoo.com/MapsService/V1/geocode?appid=user123%26street%3D4511%20horizon%20hill%20ste%2E%20150%26city%3Dsan%20antonio%26state%3DTX%26zip%3D78229"

Comment: here is what i did    url = "http://api.local.yahoo.com/MapsService/V1/geocode?appid=" & yahoo & URLEncode("&street=") & URLEncode(street) & URLEncode("&city=") & URLEncode(city) & URLEncode("&state=") & URLEncode(state) & URLEncode("&zip=") & URLEncode(zip)

Comment: Jenny, please look at my previous comment. _Don't_ encode '&zip=', but _do_ encode the value that comes after it. (likewise for the rest of the query parameters).